# Disable LINUX mode in Emacs

Tags: linux

I am using Emacs 25.3 on Mac and when I try to open some linux kernel code, the behavior is different as below:

1. I cannot simply open a C file, but I am prompted for arch each time.
2. Occasionally, emacs tries to 'parse' all the include files (I can see in the minibuf). Plus, when I use Tramp, this takes even longer and emacs is as good as hanged.

Looks like it is the linux development environment that is causing this, but when I try to disable through 'M-x global-ede-mode', EDE is actually getting enabled (I see that it writes an ede-projects.el file).

I simply want to open and edit files, and will use other tools for build and config. Any help is appreciated.

The messages after choosing the file are -

'Select Linux' build directory', and
'Select target architecture'.

Comment: What exactly is the prompt when "prompted for arch"? What happens if you invoke emacs without any of your customizations with `emacs -q`? If that solves it, then one of your customizations is the culprit.

Comment: But did you try with `emacs -q`? I don't recognize these messages, so I suspect it's some package that you load that causes this.